# Subquery not functioning and returning expression error

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a simple subquery that returns a value, however I get an error as follows:
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

The subquery is as follows.

```
SELECT
manufacturing_tote.mft_tote_barcode
FROM dbo.manufacturing_tote
INNER JOIN dbo.works_order
ON manufacturing_tote.mft_wo_id = works_order.wo_id
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: Without the whole query is hard to know. Try IN instead of =, maybe?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the subquery, it's a problem with your main query.

Comment: We really need to see the outer query and how it's calling this subquery.

Comment: You could simply use 'SELECT TOP 1' or 'SELECT MAX(...)' in the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how the subquery is being used.  If it is being used for a comparison, for instance, then the following are possible:

- replacing `=` with `in`
- using `ANY`, `SOME`, or `ALL` before the subquery

A more general solution is to ensure that it returns only one row.  There are two methods:

- Change the `select` to aggregation:  `select max(manufacturing_tote.mft_tote_barcode)`, for instance.
- Limit the result set to one row:  `select top 1 manufacturing_tote.mft_tote_barcode`.

Answer (score 0):

if the relation is indeed 1-to-many and you don't want duplicate results add DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT manufacturing_tote.mft_tote_barcode
FROM dbo.manufacturing_tote, dbo.works_order
WHERE manufacturing_tote.mft_wo_id = works_order.wo_id
```

When the result can have multiple different values, you have to decide how you want to use it:

- only fetch the first result
- use IN instead of '=' as already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You subquery return more then  a result so you should use an in clause

```
where yout_col  in   (SELECT
    manufacturing_tote.mft_tote_barcode
    FROM dbo.manufacturing_tote
    INNER JOIN dbo.works_order
    ON manufacturing_tote.mft_wo_id = works_order.wo_id)
```